# Badly formed hyperref link boxes when using certain fonts with fontspec in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, fontspec, links

Question: How to use `fontspec` fonts so that `hyperref` boxes are well formed and not too high?

**Solved:** I don't know why but adding `Extension=.ttf` inside `setmainfont` options solves this.

What I expected: To use different fonts like Junicode with XeLaTeX using the `fontspec` package in a document that has `hyperref` links.

What I got: Link boxes are too high above the glyphs, as seen in the figure below. I have tested with Junicode and Cardo.

[image: Badly formed link boxes]

This is especially annoying when the boxes are not even visible in any sensibly typeset document (try uncommenting the `colorlinks` line in the MWE).

As a reference, below is a figure where everything works nicely with the default Computer Modern font. Also, TeX Gyre Pagella and TeX Gyre Termes seem to work.

[image: Well formed link boxes with the default font]

It seems that the fonts Junicode and Cardo themselves are the cause of this but is there some way to sidestep the issue?

MWE:

```
% To compile and experience the problem: xelatex file.tex

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Mapping=tex-text,
  Extension=.ttf %%% THIS LINE SOLVED THE PROBLEM
]{Junicode}

\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}%
\urlstyle{rm}%
%%% You can try uncommenting the `colorlinks` option to experience how
%%% uncomfortable it is to try to click those invisible boxes that have
%%% wrong dimensions.
\hypersetup{%
  xetex,%
  %colorlinks=true%
}

\begin{document}

Test link: \href{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}{CC BY-SA}\\

Curiously italics work: \href{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}{\textit{CC BY-SA}}\\

test some more \href{https://www.google.com}{\MakeLowercase{Google}} and more\\

Finnish newspaper! \href{https://www.hs.fi/}{Helsingin Sanomat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: looks ok for me. Which tex system and which pdf viewer do you use? Side remark: it is quite unnecessary to use the xetex option, hyperref detects this on its own.

Comment: Good to hear that it might be just a problem on my end. Are my software versions too old?
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) and kpathsea version 6.3.2, XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020). Viewer: Evince 3.38.0.

Comment: I can't be sure but my guess is that your xdvipdfmx is too old, one windows I have a newer version in texlive 2020. You could install the texlive2021 pretest to check.

Comment: Makes sense, xdvipdfmx could generate those faulty boxes. I will have to check the new version later. Thanks!

Comment: Updated. I made sure that it really was the new version XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021).. Still same problem with Junicode but e.g. TeX Gyre Termes works nicely. Somehow the fonts are different from TeX Gyre fonts etc. or maybe the PDF rendering engine has a bug. Evince, Xournal, Okular and Firefox all show the bad boxes.

Comment: I don't know why but adding `Extension=.ttf` inside `setmainfont` options solves this. Finally.

Comment: Perhaps you have more than one version of the fonts. Add \XeTeXtracingfonts =1 and then check the log file.

Comment: Thank you, this really solves the issue. Without `Extension=.ttf` it uses the font in my home directory `~./.fonts/Junicode.ttf`. With the extension option, it uses the font from the LaTeX directory, and this font probably is more compatible with LaTeX than the plain ttf in my home directory (which is weird, but OK).